# Swift error thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION cell definition

Tags: xcode, swift

I am having trouble defining a cell with my table. It allows a user to search for a city this is the code that is giving me trouble. This is the entire code for the view controller. The goal is to allow the user to search for a city in the list of them.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreData

  class SearchBar: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate{
var searchActive : Bool = false
var data: [String] = ["San Francisco","New York","San Jose","Chicago","Los Angeles","Austin","Seattle"]
var filtered: [String] = []
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var checkavailability: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var addselected: UIBarButtonItem!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
/* Setup delegates */
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    searchActive = true
}
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
searchActive = false
}
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
searchActive = false
}
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
searchActive = false
}
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

filtered = data.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
let tmp: NSString = text
let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
return range.location != NSNotFound

})

if(filtered.count == 0){
    searchActive = false;
}
else {
    searchActive = true;
}
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if(searchActive) {
        return filtered.count
}
else {
        return data.count
}
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell!
if(searchActive == true){
    cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
 }
    else {
     cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row] \\ this is where the error comes up 
       }
    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try tableView instead of TableView, i.e. with a lowercase 't'. Lowercase tableView is a class instance, uppercase TableView is a class.

Comment: when I do that I get an error in the else statement. the same exact one.

Comment: @SaiKappagantula, what are `filtered` and `data` in your code? You haven't included the code that declares them in your question, so we have no way of helping you with that. For all we know, data and filtered are undeclared or uninitialized variables.

Comment: The other things:
- change 'let' to 'var' since you modify it,
- check whether tableView.dequeue returns nil. You have to define the first cell of type "cell" for tableView. You can either do this programmatically checking for nil, then preparing such a cell here, or in the Interface Builder (if you use it for this app)

Comment: sorry bout that I shall edit the question with more code